# iTextSharp + How to invoke the form button field click event programmatically though vb.net

Tags: vb.net, button, itext, invoke

I've have a editable pdf with button fields in it. I'm processing this editable pdf in my vb.net application using iTextsharp. I want to know, how to programmatically invoke the button field inside the pdf. Though, I'm using iTextSharp dll, I could not find any helpful resource to invoke and handle the button events. Please guide me how to invoke the button events of pdf, programmatically using vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

iText[Sharp] doesn't *execute* the Javascript within a PDF.  It can add/remove/change the scripts present, but won't run them.

For that you need a PDF viewer from Adobe, Appligent, or Foxit (alphabetical order, though Adobe's will be the best at running script, it also puts security restraints on what you can or cannot do).